# How to use i18n with Angular mat-table

Tags: angular, mat-table

I cannot seem to translate dynamic column titles using i18n and Angular's mat-table.

I tried using i18n-title [title]="field.i18n" and i18n-header [header]="field.18n" and i18n-table-header table-header="field.i18n" without any success.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let field of tableData" [matColumnDef]="field.name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [i18n]="field.i18n">
          {{field.name}}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          {{element[field.dbField]}}
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="getDisplayedColumns();"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: getDisplayedColumns();" ></tr>
    </table>
```

I would expect the column title to come from field.name using i18n templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i18n` is not a directive. It doesn't exist at runtime.

It's just an attribute used at **compile** time to extract and reinsert the static values to translate from/into the template.

If you're trying to translate a key at runtime with Angular i18n, then too bad, because it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the `localeId` of the app, and create the labels in the component. Is not nice but at least it works.

```
constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) protected localeId: string) {
      console.log(this.localeId);
}
```

And in your component you can assign the names of the headers depending the locale

```
if (this.localeId == 'de') {
/// Your code
}
```